# How do I get specific children classes from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

I've got a class called "Entity", this is extended by other classes such as "Player" and the "Slime" mob. In another class called "Level" I have an ArrayList called entities, now I add these separate classes to the ArrayList.

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    entities.add(entity);
}
```

How do I check, while looping through the ArrayList, if the current object is either a Player or Slime?

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    if (entity == Player) {
        System.out.println("Player class!");
    }
}
```

Obviously that doesn't work, but how can I do that? Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `instanceof` operator which checks the type of an object.

```
for (Entity entity : entities) {
    if (entity instanceof Player) {
        System.out.println("Player class!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `instanceof` operator to check the type of an Object.

**Example**

```
if(entity instanceof Slime)
{
    // Is a mob.
}
```

**Explanation**

For fuller details on how `instanceof` works, check out this [link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/90094-instanceof-keyword/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
if(entity instanceof Player)
//do something
```